# StructureMap ReleaseAndDisposeAllHttpScopedObjects does not cause Dispose calls

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, structuremap

I am calling ObjectFactory.ReleaseAndDisposeAllHttpScopedObjects() in Application_EndRequest which is firing as expected, however it is not causing any Http-Scoped instances inside the container from being Dispose'd of. If I call WhatDoIHave in Application_EndRequest, I can see the Http-Scoped instances that I want to have Dispose called on, but it doesn't happen! Any ideas why not?

When I look in HttpContext.Current.Items StructureMap hasn't stashed anything in there and I'm guessing it should have? An example of an item registered to be request scoped is as follows:

```
For<IConnectionProvider>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use<ConnectionProvider>();
```

IConnectionProvider inherits from IDisposable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my noob! Had an object higher up the dependency graph configured as Singleton scoped, thus hanging onto the object (connection provider) that I wanted to be disposed of at the end of each request! Changing the scoping of this object from Singleton to Transient caused everything to start working as I wanted it to!